# Release App to Apple and Google Stores - Demo account, only company users and User Generated Content scope

Tags: licensing, google, appstore, apple

I develop for a company an Ionic cross-platform mobile app that will be published on Apple's App Store and Google's Play Store.
I read Apple's [Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) and Google's [Developer Program Policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10177647) but couldn't find, even after searching over the internet, answers to some specific questions.

---

Some important things to know about the app and it's content:

- The app can only be used by the company's employees, which means that to use the app you will have to sign in through the company's portal. There is no way for lambda users to create a new account on their own to access the app.
- Users can generate content with this app but they can only see their own content on the mobile app. (There is a web interface where admins can see other's content but this is not possible on the mobile app)
- Some users are external employees with only private phones for which the company can create an account to access the app but cannot manage the device with either Apple Business Manager or Android Enterprise

---

Questions for which I couln't find clear answers are the following:

1. Is a demo mode with local static values accepted during Apple's App Review or does it have to go through the normal login process and make real API calls to the backend?
   If it has to do real API calls: is using a specific demo endpoint with fictional values only for this demo user allowed?
   *(Demo endpoints will then be different from production endoints)*
   *links: [Apple - (Intro) Before You Submit](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#before-you-submit) - [Apple - (2.1) App Completeness](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#app-completeness)*
2. As users can only see their own content on the mobile app, is this app concerned by all the requirements specific to User Generated Content (like filtering/reporting offensive/inappropriate content)?
   *(Question is for Apple's App Store and Google's Play Store)*
   *links: [Apple - (1.2) User Generated Content](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-generated-content) - [Google - User Generated Content](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9876937?hl=en&ref_topic=9877466)*
3. As we cannot use Apple Business Manager due to external employees and private phones, can we still publish the app in Apple's public App Store if lambda users cannot setup their own account to access the app? (If not, what could be a solution here?)
   *links: [Apple - (4.8) Sign in with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple)*
4. As we cannot use Android Enterprise due to external employees and private phones, can we still publish the app in Google's public Play Store if lambda users cannot setup their own account to access the app? (If not, what could be a solution here?)

I know that the last two questions are identical but as they target two really different environments I prefered to split it in two.
If my questions are lacking info don't hesitate to ask me, I'm quite new to licensing and ToS.

Comment: see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Comment: Oh thanks, I wasn't aware of this.
Makes complely sens!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide Apple with information that allows setting up an account on some server of yours and to test the application. That should be a completely functional server. Can be a server equivalent in function to your production server or eben your production server. You would provide the exact some information that you would hand to a genuine new end user.